# Wordpress page content is not displaying

Tags: wordpress

You can see it in action here: http://www.topscience-grant.com/test2/

I am using the following loop code:

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo the_content();
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    echo 'no posts found';
}
```

I have put this code in index.php of my theme and in WP admin, i created a page called home (which i assigned as static front page on appearance->customize).

Then I entered some test content in the text editor of 'home' page. Why is that text content not displaying and 'no posts found' display?

Please help.

Comment: You're doing far more than you need to.  If you want to display content for a single page, you don't need a new WP_Query, you can simply do `if (have_posts() { the_post(); the_content(); }` and that's all you need.  A "loop" is only needed for the "blog" page, and a custom loop (like what you have) is only needed for special cases where you want to show all entries that meet a certain criteria.

Comment: @cale_b Hi, I tried replacing it with your code, but still the page content won't display. http://www.topscience-grant.com/test2/

Comment: You need to provide more debugging info in order for someone to help.  Does the code even get inside the `if` condition? If so, what do you see if you add `var_dump( $post );`?  Etc.

Comment: Because `index.php` isn't for the static front page. You should be using `front-page.php`. `index.php` is used for the page for your posts.